# Blazor client WASM form validation in component not working

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly

Im having trouble getting from validation to work properly in a Blazor WASM client application.

Encapsulating an InputText element to a component for compact layout does no longer perform validation that is executed correctly otherwise.

using model like

```cs
public class Customer {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)
    public string customerName {get; set;} = "";
}
```

in a form of

```html
<EditForm Model=@customer>

<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />

<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group mb-0 col-sm-12">

        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-1 mt-1">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" style="width:6em;">Firma</span>
            </div>
            <InputText type="text" class="form-control" @bind-Value=customer.customerName />
        </div>

    </div>
</EditForm>
```

the validation works fine!

But to modularize I outsource the inner stuff to an separate component

```cs
@page "/inputGroup"

    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-1 mt-1">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="width:6em;">@label</span>
        </div>
        <InputText type=@type class="form-control" @bind-Value=@data @oninput=@onChange />
    </div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string label {get; set;} = "Label:";

    [Parameter]
    public string type {get; set;} = "text";

    [Parameter]
    public string data {get; set;} = "";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> dataChanged {get; set;}

    private Task onChange(ChangeEventArgs e) {

        data = (string)e.Value;
        return dataChanged.InvokeAsync(data);
    }
}
```

Then I put this to my form, like

```html
...
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group mb-0 col-sm-12">
        <InputGroup label="Firma:" @bind-data=customer.customerName />
    </div>
</div>
...
```

the validation is not working!?

Comment: Could you update your pasted code to show where the EditForm is?
Also, why does your embeddedable component have a `@page` directive? Do you intend to allow the user to navigate to `/inputGroup`?

Comment: `@bind-data=customer.customerName` is that a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this where you subclass `InputText`

`InputTextGroup.razor`

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText

<div class="mt-1">
       <input type="text" id="@Id"
           @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString"
           class="@CssClass myOtherCssClasses" />
</div>

@if (ValidationFor != null)
{
    <div class="myValidationClass">
        <ValidationMessage For="ValidationFor" />
    </div>
}
```

And `InputTextGroup.razor.cs`

```
public partial class InputTextGroup
{
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; } = HeadlessUI.HtmlElement.GenerateId();
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>>? ValidationFor { get; set; }
}
```

I took inspiration from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57326353/10177987) and this [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputtext-based-on-the-input-event)